# Mtgox account verification pending, how to withdraw my bitcoins?

Tags: mtgox, withdrawal, verification

I had submitted my personal document for verification over 30 days; however, my account still pending for verification, what I can do to withdraw my bitcoin?

Comment: This is a question probably best asked on the MtGox support site.

Comment: Use a different exchange?

Answer (score 1):

all the new accounts created since a few months have to be verified for any withdrawals, including bitcoins, as stated in a big warning on every page of mtgox :

"Attention Users: All withdrawals and deposits require account verification."

so yes you ll have to wait for your verification to be processed before you can withdraw anything.

the delays seem to be around 5-6 weeks, so . ..  if you already waited one month you should soon get an answer, you will  receive an email when your verification is processed.